# JavaScript won't show/hide div - working with PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

In my PHP/MySQL while loop when selecting data for an activity feed, I'm trying to show comments underneath each post so that when you click "show", it shows all of the comments.

I'm using the following code in the while loop (so this is dynamically displayed numerous times for each separate update):

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle' . $act_item_id . '() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText' . $act_item_id . '");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText' . $act_item_id . '");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "show";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "hide";
    }
} 
</script>

<a id="displayText' . $act_item_id . '" href="javascript:toggle' . $act_item_id . '();">show</a>
<div id="toggleText' . $act_item_id . '" style="display: none">' . $responseList . '</div>
```

' . $act_item_id . ' contains the ID of the update, making everything unique.

When you click show, the JavaScript doesn't show the div.

FYI: Content is loaded into another page via an AJAX call.

AJAX call is as follows:

```
function list_activity(){
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (hr.readyState==4 && hr.status==200){
    document.getElementById("viewActivity").innerHTML = hr.responseText;
    }
    }
    hr.open("GET", "listActivity.php?t=" + Math.random(), true);
    hr.send();
}
```

Comment: Why would you put all this into a php string, if you can use this?: ?> html goes here <?

Comment: Is all of that code inside a PHP string enclosed with single quotes? `'`

Comment: Apparently. It looks rather funny, actually.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Yeah, the string it's within is enclosed with single quotes

Comment: Please show the generated HTML as well, and look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to.

Comment: Also, have you tried viewing the source?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP The source is correct. Basically, the file is called listActivity.php, and the request is made to that file via AJAX to load it into another page. It doesn't work in the other page, but it works when you access the listActivity.php file directly

Comment: maybe you should try debugging your code, even using simple alerts might help. Put an alert("test") at the top of your function and if it doesn't pop-up when you click the link you know it's not finding it right? You can do this with the txt and elm variables as well.

Comment: That would have been relevant information to add in the question, don't you think? Apparently the AJAX call doesn't execute JavaScript in the response.

Comment: @Juhana Oh doesn't it? Is there a way that I can make it execute JS?

Comment: It should, but it depends on the code you use at the moment.

Comment: @Juhana I've added the AJAX code I'm using to the question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure you can create and call JS functions like that.  Besides, I don't see any reason to re-create the function for each section.  Why don't you simply parameterize you function and change the parameter each time through?

Define function once

```
<script>
function toggle(act_item_id) {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText' . act_item_id . '");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText' . act_item_id . '");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "show";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "hide";
    }
} 
</script>
```

Then you can loop through

```
while (some condition) {
    ...
    <a id="displayText' . $act_item_id . '" href="javascript:toggle('.$act_item_id.');">show</a>
    <div id="toggleText' . $act_item_id . '" style="display: none">' . $responseList . '</div>
    ...
}
```

Comment: So a PHP function wrapping JS?

Comment: Still doesn't work. I think I need to somehow enable AJAX to execute JavaScript when it's loaded, how do I do that?

Comment: Now you're diving into multiple questions.  I would say figure one out first.  Maybe check if your toggle() script is working first - use dummy text.  Then isolate your AJAX call and see if it's working.  Typically, you make your AJAX call and then the callback function is supposed to call your HTML update function (toggle?).

Comment: @dispake I know my toggle function is working because it works when I access the file directly at listActivity.php; just doesn't work when loaded into a different page with AJAX.

Comment: I get a JavaScript error: Uncaught ReferenceError: toggle20 is not defined

Comment: Did you check if it is?